# How many hours would it take to go through the LFS tutorial?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to determine how appropriate it would be for me to learn Linux by building LFS using [this tutorial](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter01/how.html)

What is the time commitment involved in getting through this and if I'm already running Fedora 13 - Will I need to either

- reformat my machine
- keep a second partition for the dev version?

Comment: Eleventy-seven. And KVM.

Comment: the only thing I understood in that comment was "And"....

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_and_Configuring_Fedora_KVM_Virtualization

Comment: thanks for the link. What about the "eleventy-seven" part?

Comment: It's a number that doesn't exist, since the experience is purely subjective.

Comment: yup, many is as good an answer as any.  you can accelerate your progress a LOT by using a package manager and rebuilding source packages to suit your needs.

Comment: I must say, that from my standpoint, building LFS is a little too ambitious a way to "learn Linux".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends, LFS is like making a **reverse-autopsy**.

Depending on your previous knowledges and what interest you much to modify, because just copying command lines from the text is useless and error prone.

LFS is like model making. It will not fly well, but it yours.

So let me send your question back. How many time do you have to put in your personal almost-working tweaked proudly-owned linux build?

Answer (score 1):

A third alternative you didn't cover was installing LFS in a virtual machive such as KVM, so that your main system can keep running even while you puzzle how to put the guest together.

Comment: @Ramy: I think shellholic's was the better answer. I'm only adding this as an adjunct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the first time to try installing LFS. From beginning until chapter 8.23 (Installing Basic System Software) is about 24 hour (include 4 hour for sleep). I install it in real machine.